# 2 node elasticsearch cluster for production like environment

Tags: elasticsearch

From below document, I am trying to find if I can use 2 node cluster for production like environment. I know 3 node cluster is always better choice.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-small-clusters.html#high-availability-cluster-design-two-nodes

link above says, if you create 2 node es cluster, then make one of them as `node.master: false` so that node will not participate in election when either node is unavailable, so we have one master (and may be data node also) and other as only data node (i.e not master role)

It also says, The cluster can tolerate the loss of the other `master-ineligible node`. So it means after having above setting, there is no impact if non-master node is down, not available for some time.

but its not clear what will happen if the master node goes down? (I know all master node activity like creation/deletion of indices or shard allocation will not happen) but will the other data node continue receiving writes and responding to client requests? If yes then what will be the impact until master node come back and join cluster?

below link says, if one fails the other node can handle its tasks.

We recommend you assign both nodes all other roles except master eligibility. If one node fails, the other node can handle its tasks

and here it says this configuration is not resilient to failure.

Because it’s not resilient to failures, we do not recommend deploying a two-node cluster in production.

The above two line mismatching to me.

Below is another link from elastic which says, if single master node goes down writes will be blocked but what if other data node is still live, will it not accept and respond to requests meanwhile?

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/3-nodes-in-the-cluster-2-data-and-1-master-why-if-one-fails-it-takes-the-whole-cluster-down/267165/2?u=cool999

I am trying to find the impact of single master node failure on 2 node cluster and reason to use three node cluster instead.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find the impact of single master node failure on 2 node
> cluster and reason to use three node cluster instead.

If you lose the master node in a 2-nodes cluster, your entire cluster will stop working and it will not answer to requests, the data nodes are always communicating with the master node, so without the master node it is not able to answer to requests.

A 2-nodes cluster is not fault tolerant, you can't lose the master node, if you want some kind of fault tolerancy you need at least 3 master-eligible nodes, in this configuration you can afford to lose 1 master node.